# TypeScript's as const v JavaScript's Map object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple object:

```
const simpleObject = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: 'three'
}
```

Now, I understand that pre ES2015 objects could not be guaranteed to return keys in the same order that they were inserted. But this is not such a problem these days.

We are using TypeScript and the question of the effect of whether `as const` would in fact maintain key order came up:

```
const simpleObject = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: 'three'
} as const
```

It is unclear what effect `as const` would have.

JavaScript's `Map` object does maintain key order and so could be used instead of the object above.

So what can be used and what is best to be used when we want key order to be preserved?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. First, an object is not a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you show an object but you're asking about a Map. Secondly the question makes no sense at the type level, because Typescript is structurally typed and `type A { a: number b: string }` is "equivalent" to `type B { b: string, a: number }`. Are asking for is a compile-time guarantee of the key order in an object? I don't think that's possible. If key order is important you would have to write run-time normalization code.

Comment: You could also use instances of a user-defined class instead of POJOs, those should maintain property order.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Both plain objects (as in the first example) and `Map`'s maintain key order. (`as const` does not change anything.) If you want to iterate over keys, `Map` tend to be the best choice since it doesn't have the issue of iterating over prototype properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as const` has no effect in runtime. It instructs the (typescript) compiler to infer the narrowest type for that specific expression.

You can see that in the typescript playground for simplicity, [by looking at the transpiled code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWBbADgGwKYHkBGArdwsAvDAN4BQMM46AXDAOQ0MA0lMUA7iPQ1yK3ZQAFgCd0dRiPHoG5AL4wAhhBihIUIA)

If the order of the keys matters, [use a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), since as mentioned above `as const` does not have any effect in runtime whatsoever.

To answer to the question `It is unclear what effect as const would have`, the answer is that for the **developer experience** it will give you a narrower type, but it won't have any effect in runtime.

Comment: So, is the order of keys in objects still not certain for integer keys? For string keys, why not just use a plain object?

Comment: @JoeTidee It should, but I wouldn't use a plain object anyway. There is no real advantage of using a plain object instead of a Map for such a scenario, and Maps are more suitable in general. As far as I know, since ES2015 integer keys insertion order should be certain, but once again, I would not use an object anyway in that scenario specifically :)

Comment: @JoeTidee Honestly if it matters that much define a custom class with an [Symbol.iterator method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) that yields the properties in the desired order. As for `as const` remember that Typescript has type literals. In a normal pojo the type of e.g. one is string but if you use `as const` the *type* is the *literal string* "one".  Also for arrays it will infer the array as a tuple type.